# How to route IsEnabledChanged (not routed event) to an EventHandler WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, event-handling, isenabled

I'm simply trying to reset the value of a NumericUpDown element in xaml to 0 when IsEnabled becomes false, but checking for IsEnabled changes is not a routed event. This is what I currently have which doesn't work because this event is not a Routed Event

My XAML code:

```
<CheckBox Name="AirportTemplate">Airport</CheckBox>

      <NumericUpDown Name="AirportToGen"
                     Width="300"
                     Minimum="0"
                     IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=AirportTemplate, Path=IsChecked}"
                     IsEnabledChanged="ResetValueAirport"/>
```

My Code Behind C#

```
private void ResetValueAirport(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!AirportToGen.IsEnabled)
            {
                AirportToGen.Value = 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using the `NumericUpDown` class form the extended WPF toolkit, in which case the `IsEnabledChanged` event requires a handler with the signature `private void handler(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)`.  So in your code behind use this instead:

```
private void ResetValueAirport(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!AirportToGen.IsEnabled)
        {
            AirportToGen.Value = 0;
        }
    }
```